# What is the difference between categories of countries in the extradition act 2003?

Tags: england-and-wales, criminal-procedure, extradition

What is the purpose of dividing countries into different categories at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Category 2 countries are those that implement the European Arrest Warrant framework](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/libertycentral/2008/dec/16/extradition-act) which allows for a simplified and uniform extradition process between such countries.

Category 1 countries are those that have extradition treaties with the United Kingdom.